# Use of pointers in dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can someone explain to me why when I dynamic allocate memory with `calloc` or `malloc` I declare:

```
int *arr
int n
arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int))
```

and not

```
*arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the first example you are making `arr` the pointer to the memory. In the second example you are making what `arr` is pointing to the pointer to the memory allocated.

In other words, you declared arr as a pointer. Malloc returns a pointer to allocated memory. So you "fill" arr with that value. In your second example, you are filling *arr--what arr is pointing to--with the value returned by malloc.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an `int *`, i.e. "pointer to `int`". When you dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`, you get a pointer that points to that memory, and should assign it to a variable, in this case, `arr`.

`*arr` (i.e., the dereference of `arr`) would just be an `int`. `*arr` is the value that `arr` points to, not the pointer (address) itself.

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet:

```
int *arr
int n
arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

there is set the value of the variable (pointer) `arr` with the address of the allocated memory.

In this statement:

```
*arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

the pointed object by the pointer `arr` that has the type `int` is set by the address of the allocated memory. However the pointer `arr` was not initialized and does not point to a valid object. Moreover the expression `*arr` has the type int while the right hand side expression has the type `void *`. So the compiler will issue an error.

You need to set the value of the pointer itself not the value of the pointed by the pointer object.